# OpenLayers Enable KML feature based on user form

Tags: openlayers-2, kml

I have a KML layer with over 300 features, but I only want to display features based on a user form.

Each feature has a unique ID and Sector and I have added the entire KML to the map but have the visibility set to false.  How would I go about adding only the features to the map that contain the unique ID and Sector values specified after a user hits submit on a form?

Comment: Please checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995238/refresh-redraw-a-layer-in-openlayers-kml-network-link-auto-refresh/11333611#11333611 might be helpful for you.

Comment: I've decided to install and use Geoserver instead of just loading KML layers...and each of the geoserver openlayers examples offer a query data function.